# Unable to access router home page

Tags: router, dhcp, ping, network-discovery

1. I am Unable to ping router at 192.168.10.1
2. I want to access the router to change wireless security passphrase

Why I am not able to access with web browser?

Machine Details:
Win7, IP: 192.168.10.103, DNS: 255.255.255.0

[image: IPConfig When on Wifi]

Tried with DHCP and Static IP.

With tracert, it shows hop to router i.e. 192.168.10.1

tracert log to www.google.com:
[image: tracert google.com]

Comment: ICMP is commonly disabled on networking devices, be it by default or by configuration. Not getting a response from `ping` does not definitively conclude if the device is up or down.

Comment: Maybe your router is set to block ping? My router has such option enabled by default, it's only for pings from the Internet though.

Comment: Ping is a very common utility, how come the device had ICMP disabled, then how I am able to access internet.. see my tracert logs.

Comment: @TomYan, How come by default ping is blocked.. I am also trying to access http page with the gateway ip address.. but not able to do so.. does tcp packets are also dropped?

Comment: Common mistake some members make is formatting. Your post is just some bullet points with no actual question. We can guess what you are asking, but may be wrong. Taking a minute to [edit] your question to make it more clear what you are asking. This may increase your chances of getting the help you seek.

Comment: If you can't access it through http either then maybe your case is not really about ICMP/ping.

Comment: Ping is a very common utility -- yes so , how come the device had ICMP disabled, then how I am able to access internet-- ICMP is not required to be able to access internet or network, many windows server/firewall blocks ICMP and you can still RDP to it. it's not magic

Comment: @SeanClt Does my firewall is also blocking http packets, when I try to access via web browser?

Comment: your question was about Ping being blocked, router could very well have a setting to block ICMP, you didn't mention your http packets are being blocked

Comment: Are you connected using wifi or ethernet when trying to access router home page?

Comment: @SeanClt yes connected to wifi

Comment: @SeanClt question edited

Comment: try connected via ethernet and then paste your ifconfig settings

Comment: @SeanClt is on the right track.  Very often, wireless routers do not allow access to configuration when connected via wireless.  Connect to your router via a cable and try again.  Most often, you can turn this limitation off, but you have to connect via a cable FIRST to do so.  It's a security thing.

Comment: ipconfig /all
http://i65.tinypic.com/161fipl.png

Comment: The ipconfig /all setting is with wireless.. I will try with ethernet and update soon...

Comment: this was a very badly written question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to connect using Wireless and trying to access router home page

I would recommend connecting using ethernet cable and then try to access your router home page

If that doesn't help, i would recommend resetting your router and then try again using ethernet cable

Answer (score 0):

Ping does not really tell you if something is not the network or not. As mentioned, default devices have ping (ICMP) shut off for security reasons. Typically something harmful will use ping to sniff out targets then begin their work on them. If they cannot ping it then it doesn't exist (usually, not always of course.)

Comment: I am trying to access http page, via web browser, but unable to do so.. are http packets also shut off?

Comment: Is this at a business or your home? It looks like you have at least 2 networks wherever it is. It's possible there is a firewall blocking this traffic. Are you going through a proxy? Have you checked IE settings to make sure you don't have one set if you're not supposed to? Or the correct ones if you are?

Comment: proxy is disabled for the time I am trying to ping. Actually I am trying to access the router homepage. I am trying to access with chrome browser. Will clearing history and cache help? what browser settings specifically do you want to make me confirm

Comment: The IE proxy settings shouldn't effect the ping, but it when you try to browse a site etc...What Sean mentioned is a good start though. Try resetting the router and plugging directly into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to do a traceroute to google.com through a terminal, but not able to load the page on the webbrowser, its very likely your firewall. Can you see if your firewall is switched off or atleast allows the chrome browser?  Ping utility is not a good method to find out if a server / gateway is reachable or not because the stacks deliberately disable this to avoid ping attacks.

Sometimes, the routers disable changing of security settings like passphrase etc through wifi. Hence you need to connect a cable to the router to change them. But I think, your case is more likely the problem on the client side ( your operating system ) and not the network i.e even if you try to access a webpage using a ethernet cable via chrome, it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that 192.168.10.1 is actually the IP address of your router? There is a great little tool called Advanced IP Scanner that simply lists all the IP addresses and hostnames of all the devices on your network. It also provides buttons to SSH, FTP, and view the device in a web browser. http://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/ With all of the routers I have ever used, tha are located at 192.168.10.0.

Comment: `192.168.10.1` is his default gateway. See the link in OP's comment to image of ipconfig output.